# Show that ab is divisible by 3 if and only if at least one of a or b is divisible by 3

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If $a, b \in \mathbb{z}$, then how might one show that $a,b$ is divisible by $3$ if and only if at least one of $a$ or $b$ is divisible by 3?

Comment: [Euclid’s lemma](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_lemma) for $p=3$

Comment: Depends on your definitions? This is the definition of primes in some constructions. In others, you can use Bezout's lemma to prove it.

Comment: The tags here seem inapplicable (real analysis and analysis).  Wouldn't elementary number theory be a suitable replacement?

Answer (score 1):

[Euclid's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_lemma) in number theory captures a fundamental property of prime integers:

if a prime $p$ divides the product $ab$ of two integers $a$ and $b$,

then $p$ must divide at least one of those integers $a$ and $b$.

In particular, if $p$ divides $a^2$ then $p$ divides $a$; this could be used in the proof that $\sqrt p$ is irrational.

In this question, $p=3.$

The usual proof of Euclid's lemma involves Bezout's identity,

which can be shown using the extended Euclidean algorithm.

Note that Euclid's lemma would not necessarily work when $p$ is not prime;

for example, $10$ divides $4 \times 25$ but $10$ does not divide $4$ or $25.$